# OAuth2 with Yahoo API

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I want to read and write to a user's [Yahoo Fantasy Sports](https://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/) data.

I'm trying to gain access via the [Yahoo API](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/) using [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift).

My OAuthSwift object looks like this:

```
let oauth2Swift = OAuth2Swift(
    consumerKey:    "*****",
    consumerSecret: "*****",
    authorizeUrl:   "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth",
    accessTokenUrl: "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token",
    responseType:   "code"
)
```

And I execute it like this:

```
    self.oauth2Swift.authorize(withCallbackURL: "com.me.myapp", scope: "fspt-w", state: "", success: { (cred, response, params) in
        print("✅ success")
    }) { (error) in
        print(" error")
    }
```

I've created an instance of the app on Yahoo's Developer Website and have made sure the callback domain matches the one used in the previous code snippet:

[image]

My iOS app successfully brings up the Yahoo login experience in the browser, however once the user logs in it shows the following error:

> Developers: Please check the redirect URI in your request and submit
>   again.

[image]

So my question is: why I am getting the above error when attempting to authorize a Yahoo user with OAuth in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Identity Provider will redirect to client application with the URL specified in the callback. Try changing the callback Url to your application's auth endpoint. I used to test with  `callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/auth/yahoo/callback"` and used to work. And offcourse the configured callback domain should match with the domain in the URL

Comment: Hi, I used that as the callback URL and am still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Are you missing the end point for handling the redirect? You could use this document [OAuth2 in Python](https://goodcode.io/static/media/OAuth2-edited.pdf) to cross check your code. I had implemented in Spring, and so I had an authentication filter on the path `/yahoo/callback` for handling the redirect.